# Is the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $(\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

The problem is to determine whether the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ $(\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$ converges or diverges.

Proof of the convergence os the series:

Let $U_n = (\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n$.

As $\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1>0 $ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have  $|U_n|^\frac{1}{n} = U_n^\frac{1}{n}$ = ( $(\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1)^n)^\frac{1}{n}$ = $\sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1$.

Then $\lim_{n \to \infty} U_n^\frac{1}{n} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sqrt[n]{2n^2}-1 = \cdots = 0 < 1$ .

Thus, by the root test, the given series converges absolutely... Is this right or do I need more explanation?

Comment: What's the "..."? Are you sure you didn't make a mistake in that?

Comment: just taking the limit so it would be = $lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(2n^2)^\frac{1}{n}$ - 1

Comment: I get $\frac{1}{e}$

Comment: It looks fine to me. Delete those three points in your last line of calculations: the limit is completely elementary and anyone not understanding it would probably not know what the subject here is. Also delete the "absolute" adjective, unless explicitly required, since you've already shown the series is positive.

Answer (score 0):

The completeness or not of the argument depends on the reader. If you think that the reader of the proof will know what the dots mean, then the proof is complete. Else, fill the details in.

Comment: the "..." is just  "=$lim_{n \to \infty}$ $(2n^2)^\frac{1}{n}$ - 1"

Comment: Does the reader know why?  :)

Comment: I mean, details like that in the middle of a proof are always a matter of taste/style.

Answer (score 0):

The logarithmic characteristic of the convergence.
$$
\\\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{\ln\frac{1}{a_n}}{\ln n}}=-\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{n\cdot \ln((2n^2)^{(1/n)}-1)}{\ln n}}=-\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n}{\ln n}\cdot\ln0>1
=>
$$
Series is convergent.